# SQL Server : automatically executed Functions

Tags: sql-server, function

Is there a way to tell SQL Server to run a function (e.g. deleting datasets which were created half a year ago) after a certain time (every day, every week...) without any third-party apps?

Ty, guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a stored procedure that will done all the things you want, and then schedule  this store procedure to run after some specific time.

To do this you can use the "SQL Server Agent" . To know how SQL server Agent configured and run
please go through the following way

1. Expand the SQL Server Agent node and right click the Jobs node in SQL Server Agent and select 'New Job'
2. In the 'New Job' window enter the name of the job and a description on the 'General' tab.
3. Select 'Steps' on the left hand side of the window and click 'New' at the bottom.
4. In the 'Steps' window enter a step name and select the database you want the query to run against.
5. Paste in the T-SQL command you want to run into the Command window and click 'OK'.
6. Click on the 'Schedule' menu on the left of the New Job window and enter the schedule information (e.g. daily and a time).
7. Click 'OK' - and that should be it.